# Infopath form - multiple reports

Tags: infopath

I am trying to create a form where people can report incidents. They should be able to report multiple incidents on one form however this is proving difficult.

The form has a drop-down list linked to a SharePoint list which has the different types of incident. There are a bunch of additional questions that get asked depending on the incident type.

I’d like to be able to repeat the entire form so if the first incident is “slip” the individual can report all the details and if they also need to report a “near miss” they can select that from the drop down and the related questions will appear.

At the moment, if I try to make the entire form a repeating section, when you “add a new incident” the drop down is populated with the details of the “slip” (first entry).

Please help!